# How to retrieve proxy info using WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

My app tests the connection to a website through the customer proxy server.

As part of the diagnostic, I would like to display the information returned by the proxy server about itself, such as the contents of the Server HTTP header (e.g.: Server: Squid/3.1.6), the proxy protocol (such as HTML),...

How do I retrieve such info returned by the proxy server in its HTTP responses?

EDIT: Unfortunately, the returned Response headers, as suggested by many, contain very few things and nothing about the proxy. I guess they are only the headers returned by the web server and forwarded by the proxy. My next idea is to make a fake CONNECT HTTP request to the proxy and see what he replies. Or is there some deeper access to the dialogue with the proxy?

NOTE: Platform requirement: .NET3 max :-(

Answer (score 0):

The response headers are stored in the [WebClient.ResponseHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders(v=vs.110).aspx) property. This property stores the headers from the last WebClient call. If you reuse the same instance for multiple calls you'll have to make sure you retrieve the values immediately after each call.

A better choice would be to use direct HttpWebRequest calls or (in .NET 4+) HttpClient so you can keep the responses of each individual call for processing.

`ResponseHeaders` is a NameValueCollection so you can reference specific headers by name, or through the  [HttpResponseHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpresponseheader(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration eg:

```
var header=myClient.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.Server];
```

You don't have to iterate over all the headers or keys if you don't want to

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the returned Response headers contain very few things and nothing about the proxy. I guess they are only the headers returned by the web server and forwarded by the proxy. My next idea is to make a fake CONNECT HTTP request to the proxy and see what he replies. Or is there some deeper access to the dialogue with the proxy?

Comment: I don't know, but you'd have to use HttpClient to send verbs other than GET/POST. This would also give you control over how requests and responses are sent.

Comment: Unfortunately, .NET4+ is not an option for deployment reasons: The app will be used by our customers for quick on-site connection tests. We cannot make any assumptions about installed runtimes. .NET3 is the max I can expect since it's part of Windows Vista+, hoping that most customers still on XP have .NET3 installed.

Comment: There's no need for such restrictions. The [.NET Client profile](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24872) is only 40MB which you can install as part of your application. Anyway, you can use HttpWebRequest directly to specify the HTTP Verb

Comment: When you call a customer with limited time and will, across the planet, to ask him to run a connectivity test for you from the factory floor on a computer where he's nothing close to computer admin, through a corporate Internet connection (not your nice private DSL line), 40MB has nothing to do with "Only" ;-)

Comment: Fiddler addresses this by providing two versions, the latest 4 version and a 2 version for people that don't want to install .NET 4+. A ClickOnce package may be a better option, as it doesn't require admin privileges

Answer (score 0):

[WebClient.ResponseHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for I think.

Assuming you are using Proxy, then all WebClient sees is the request to and from the proxy, so this will get you the headers. The proxy protocol you should already know from when you create the object...

Copied from above link:

```
// Obtain the WebHeaderCollection instance containing the header name/value pair from the response.
WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = myWebClient.ResponseHeaders;
Console.WriteLine("\nDisplaying the response headers\n");
// Loop through the ResponseHeaders and display the header name/value pairs. 
for (int i=0; i < myWebHeaderCollection.Count; i++)             
    Console.WriteLine ("\t" + myWebHeaderCollection.GetKey(i) + " = " + myWebHeaderCollection.Get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WebClient class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you are able to get all informations about proxy accessing Proxy property. If you are not, you could inspect your Request object.

Comment: The OP isn't asking about the proxy properties but the HTTP headers returned by the proxy in the *response*

Comment: That's why I told him to inspect the Request object, where we can find all informations about the request, including HTTP headers.

Comment: How would the Request object contain info returned by the server ?

Comment: @IcaroCamelo the OP is asking about the *response headers* added by intermediate (and possibly unknown) proxies to the response, not the request headers. The response may pass through many proxies, eg. a reverse proxy at the server' side, or any of the intermediate ISPs. Each of them may add its own headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to show the **Response Headers**, from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oENa2WDiyyo)

```
static void DownloadAndShowHeaders()
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            client.DownloadString("http://google.com");
            foreach (string name in client.ResponseHeaders.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name + "=" + client.ResponseHeaders[name]);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(we.Status);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```